# Pandas dataframe column names seem wrong

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm a student and therefore a rookie.  I'm trying to create a Pandas dataframe of crime statistics by neighborhood in San Francisco.  My problem is that I want the column names to be simply "Neighborhood" and "Count".  Instead I seem to be stuck with a separate line that says "('Neighborhood', 'count')" instead of the proper labels.  Here's the code:

```
df_counts = df_incidents.copy()
df_counts.rename(columns={'PdDistrict':'Neighborhood'}, inplace=True)
df_counts.drop(['IncidntNum', 'Category', 'Descript', 'DayOfWeek', 'Date', 'Time', 'Location', 'Resolution', 'Address', 'X', 'Y', 'PdId'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_totals=df_counts.groupby(['Neighborhood']).agg({'Neighborhood':['count']})
df_totals.columns = list(map(str, df_totals.columns)) # Not sure if I need this
df_totals
```

Output:

```
('Neighborhood', 'count')
Neighborhood    
BAYVIEW     14303
CENTRAL     17666
INGLESIDE   11594
MISSION     19503
NORTHERN    20100
PARK        8699
RICHMOND    8922
SOUTHERN    28445
TARAVAL     11325
TENDERLOIN  9942
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `agg()` here, you can simply do:

```
df_totals = df_counts.groupby(['Neighborhood']).count()
df_totals.columns = ['count']
df_totals = df_totals.reset_index() # flatten the column headers
```

And if you want to print the output without the numerical index:

```
print(df_totals.to_string(index=False))
```